# Is it possible to run node.js on an RTOS?

Tags: node.js, rtos

I have a [8 core ARM device](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) and I was wondering whether I could use it to build a drone. Does a real time operating system require a specific type or method of programming? Is it possible to use node.js with any of these systems?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes, it is.  Your board seems to be ARM/Linux and peopel have made node.sj for Raspberry Pi/Linux on ARM.  So, it seems like it should certainly be possible.  If you can't find anyone else who has done it already for your board, you'd have to grab the source from Github and attempt to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes it is possible to run node.js on RTOS.

**About RTOS**

1. You should remove buffer delays. For example, [don't block Node.js event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop) or don't use Node.js `process.nextTick` function.
2. Use event-based approach for better code architecture.
3. Think like an embedded developer, not like web-developer.
4. This is an interesting and not trivial job.

**About node.js details**

1. As you can see at the link the device has Linux Kernel 4.9 LTS OS.
2. You can install Node.js and npm modules on Linux Kernel 4.9 LTS OS.
3. There can be an issue to run native functionality from Node.js. You must have node.js wrapper module in c language. Good example for Raspberry Pi is [wiringpi-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiringpi-node)
4. Python can be used as a node.js alternative

Comment: "Think like an embedded developer, not like web-developer." - Can you elaborate?

Comment: Usually, web-developer doesn't think about memory, CPU utilisation and performance, because he can. Embedded developer must do it.

Comment: Shouldn't we develop the same way? I mean first develop the code which passes the tests, next optimize the code to meet with the performance requirements...

Comment: You can, but never forgot about your hardware limits. In web-development, you can easily add memory or CPU, in embedded development you can't

Comment: But... is Linux truly classified an RTOS in 2017? Are there any true RTOS solutions out there similar to Microlattice (https://github.com/iamblue/microlattice)?