# STM MP157C DK2 Is Node.js possible?

Tags: node.js, stm32

Currently i am running a Raspberry PI and STM32 in a project and i was looking into the MP1 to replace it with. As its an easier setup. 
I am running a node.js application on the raspberry and I am trying to get that application to run on the MP1. I have tried to follow the tutorials from stm32 but doesnt help that much. Has anyone done anything like this? I know the microcontroller is new as it has been released in Oktober. 
I know its a broad question. But anything helps as i cant find a lot about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run an embedded OS like Embedded Linux or RTOS on the ARM you can run node.js and  see https://elinux.org/images/1/14/Karagoz-nodejs-presentation_0.pdfhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753321/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-on-an-rtos. On a completely bare metal machine it may also be possible however this is very effortful to implement a JavaScript runtime like it was done for the *ESP32-WROVER module* (https://www.neonious.com/lowjs/)

You can implement websockets also in C/C++ that can run on bare metal ARM see https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp